# Determining the pattern direction of a bitmap image

Tags: image-processing, algorithms, opencv, c++, tensor

How can I obtain average direction of the pattern shown in the figure below. It is the direction of the red arrow relative to the yellow (horizontal) line. Any ideas for an approach? I couldn't figure out a way to approach. This is a spatio-temporal image created from a video. Thank you.

[image: Figure A]

Comment: What is exactly your problem, what have been done so far? Please edit your post.

Comment: Found solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547038/determining-the-pattern-orientation-of-a-spatiotemporal-image

Comment: glad to hear that, so please delete your post because it is considered duplicated now.

Comment: @MimSaad according to community standards it is not duplicate since "The duplicate question must exist on Signal Processing Stack Exchange"

Comment: you should be a lawyer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is using **[structure tensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_tensor)**

```
from skimage.feature import structure_tensor

Axx, Axy, Ayy = structure_tensor(gray_image, sigma=1)
tan2t = (2*Axy)/(Axx-Ayy)
t=np.arctan(tan2t)/2
data = t.ravel()

# find the mode of `data` array (can use histogram). it is the direction.
```

[another question and answers from other community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547038/determining-the-pattern-orientation-of-a-spatiotemporal-image)